# Implication of Berman and Hartmanis conjecture

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np

I am reading "Complexity and Cryptography" by Talbolt and Welsh. The book mentions the [Berman and Hartmanis conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berman%E2%80%93Hartmanis_conjecture) :

> All $NP$-Complete languages are $p$-isomorphic.

Then the book says that if the conjecture is True then $P \ne NP$. I am unable to make sense of the proof the book gives, which is:

> If $P=NP$ then all languages in $P$ are $NP$-Complete, but there are finite languages in $P$ and these cannot be $p$-isomorphic to infinite languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two languages $X$ and $Y$ are $p$-isomorphic if there's a polynomial-time computable bijection $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $w\in X\iff f(w)\in Y$.

Now, suppose that **P$\,=\,$NP**.  Assuming we're defining **NP**-completeness in terms of polynomial-time many-one reductions, every language in **NP**, except for $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ is **NP**-complete.  To see this, let $Y\in\mathbf{NP}\setminus\{\emptyset, \Sigma^*\}$ and pick two strings $w_{\mathrm{in}}\in Y$ and $w_{\mathrm{out}}\notin Y$. For any language $X\in \mathbf{NP}$, we can reduce $X$ to $Y$ in polynomial time using the function
$$f(w) = \begin{cases}
\,w_{\mathrm{in}} &\text{if }w\in X\\
\,w_{\mathrm{out}} &\text{if }w\notin X\,.
\end{cases}$$
Since $X$ can be decided in polynomial time, we can compute $f$ in polynomial time.  Note that there is a small error in the proof quoted in the question, which claims that *all* languages in **P** would be **NP**-complete if **P$\,=\,$NP**.  This is incorrect: if we took $Y=\emptyset$ or $Y=\Sigma^*$, the reduction wouldn't work because one of $w_{\mathrm{in}}$ and $w_{\mathrm{out}}$ wouldn't exist.

So, we've established that, if **P$\,=\,$NP**, then every finite language is **NP**-complete; we also know that some infinite languages, such as $\mathrm{SAT}$ are **NP**-complete.  But now suppose that there's a $p$-isomorphism between every pair of **NP**-complete languages.  That means that, in particular, there's a bijection between every finite language and $\mathrm{SAT}$. But there can't be a bijection between a finite set and an infinite set.